# How to clear Leaflet map of all markers and layers before adding new ones?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, leaflet

I have the following code:

```
map: function (events) {
    var arrayOfLatLngs = [];
    var _this = this;

    // setup a marker group
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    events.forEach(function (event) {
        // setup the bounds
        arrayOfLatLngs.push(event.location);

        // create the marker
        var marker = L.marker([event.location.lat, event.location.lng]);

        marker.bindPopup(View(event));

        // add marker
        markers.addLayer(marker);
    });

    // add the group to the map
    // for more see https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster
    this.map.addLayer(markers);

    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(arrayOfLatLngs);
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    this.map.invalidateSize();
}
```

I initially call this function and it will add all `events` to the map with markers and clusters.

At a later point I pass in some other events, the map will zoom in to the new events but the old ones are still on the map.

I've tried `this.map.removeLayer(markers);` and some other stuff, but I can't get the old markers to disappear

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you want to remove all the current layers (markers) in your group you can use the `clearLayers` method of `L.markerClusterGroup()`. Your reference is called `markers` so you would need to call:

```
markers.clearLayers();
```

Comment: I tended to add my map layers to 'var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup()' so I use this code 'this.editableLayers.clearLayers()'  in order to clear shapes which I drew on the map.

Comment: With this approach you clear all the markers added to `markerClusterGroup`. If you want to keep the markers for later usage, it's better due to performance issues to simply remove the cluster group from the map with `map.removeLayer(markers)`

Comment: L.markerClusterGroup() is not part of Leaflet by default; it can be replaced with L.layerGroup()

Answer (score 34):

You're losing the marker reference because it's set with var.
Try saving the references to 'this' instead.

```
mapMarkers: [],
map: function (events) {
    [...]
    events.forEach(function (event) {
        [...]
        // create the marker
        var marker = L.marker([event.location.lat, event.location.lng]);
        [...]
        // Add marker to this.mapMarker for future reference
        this.mapMarkers.push(marker);
    });
    [...]
}
```

Then later when you need to remove the markers run:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.mapMarkers.length; i++){
    this.map.removeLayer(this.mapMarkers[i]);
}
```

Alternatively, instead of saving each reference to each marker, you can just save the cluster to 'this'.

Comment: thanks, `markers.clearLayers();` did the trick, but you had a good point using `this` otherwise i couldn't do it

Answer (score 7):

```
map._panes.markerPane.remove();
```

Comment: its just remove image !

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".leaflet-marker-icon").remove();
$(".leaflet-popup").remove();
```

Comment: for me there was also a shadow .leaflet-marker-shadow

Answer (score -1):

You can clear all markers withought saving it

```
map.eachLayer((layer) => {
  if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
     layer.remove();
  }
});
```

from https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-event

Comment: This removes the entire map.

Answer (score -4):

I used a combination of the two best answers here from beije and Prayitno Ashuri.

Saving the markers to "this" so we can reference it later.

```
this.marker = L.marker([event.location.lat, event.location.lng]);
```

and then just removing the markers.

```
this.markers.remove()
```

Comment: this.marker != this.markers , also make this.markers needs to be an array or object ?