# Clearing markers using leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, leaflet

I am trying to clear markers if a new sidebar filter is selected. I am populating markers using the wordpress API. Is there a way that on click of a sidebar checkbox i can erase the markers before redrawing them? Im stuck for where i add it. I have a function called getLatLong that pulls the lat and long from the api, and some other data.

```
let markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    
    await fetch(api_url).then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                getLatLong(response[i].ID).then(
                    marker => addMarker(marker, markers)
                );
            }
        });

    function addMarker(marker_point, markers){
    
            markers.addLayer(L.marker([marker_point[0].lat, marker_point[0].long], {icon: myIcon})
                        .bindPopup(marker_point[0].title+"<a href='" + marker_point[0].link + "'>Learn more</a>")
                        .addTo(map));
    
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clear Leaflet map of all markers and layers before adding new ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636723/how-to-clear-leaflet-map-of-all-markers-and-layers-before-adding-new-ones)

Answer (score 0):

You can group all the markers in a FeatureGroup (https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup)
Then you can use the inherited methods from the Layer Group addTo() and removeFrom() to show them on the Map or remove them again.